# How can I put an object property inside ngClass?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code:

```
<td *ngFor="let prop of props"
 [ngClass] = "{
    componentClasses[prop]: true
 }"
>
 Something
</td>
```

componentClasses looks like this:

```
componentClasses = {'id': 'class1', 'name': 'class2', 'salary': 'class3'};
```

this.props looks like this:

```
this.props = ['id', 'name', 'salary'];
```

Why do I want to do this? So that I won't hardcode every class. I would automate it instead, which is useful if you have a big table with different css properties.

**The problem is:**

This syntax doesn't work. ngClass doesnt seem to like this kind of structure inside `object[prop]:`.

I tried the code below as well, but without any success.
'`$(componentClasses[prop])$`': true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some reduddant code
`[ngClass]="componentClasses[prop]"`

**UPDATE:**
pass it as an array:

```
[ngClass]="[componentClasses[prop], componentClasses[prop] + '1' ]"
```

Answer (score 1):

in html we use props only not this.props

```
<td *ngFor="let prop of props"
 [ngClass] = "{
    componentClasses[prop]: true
 }"
>
 Something
</td>
```

Comment: I tested both of them and the problem is still occuring.

Comment: this is how we use it                                                                                                            <some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

Answer (score 0):

move it to the ts? Also, use the `ngFor` will result in multiple `td`

```html
<td 
 [ngClass] = "classNames"
>
 Something
</td>
```

```
componentClasses = {'id': 'class1', 'name': 'class2', 'salary': 'class3'}
props = ['id', 'name', 'salary']
get classNames(){
  return this.props.reduce((acc,key)=>acc[componentClasses[key]]=true,{})
}
```

or

```
componentClasses = {'id': 'class1', 'name': 'class2', 'salary': 'class3'}
props = ['id', 'name', 'salary']
get classNames(){
  return this.props.map((key)=>componentClasses[key])
}
```

Comment: In "Something"'s place should be each cell corresponding to id, name and salary, I need more tds. I still have some conditions left that I have to put in the ngClass, besides componentClasses[prop]. I need to be able to use this componentClasses[prop] there.